# How can I communicate with all the users of a Trello board inside Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-boards

I am using Trello to manage a project that I am doing with some of my students and I am finding that there are times when it would be useful to send a message to all of the users of the board about some change that was made to the board  (i.e., meta-Trello).

**Is it possible to send a message to board members that is not associated with a specific card?** (I know I can use `@user` within card comments)

If it is not, what is the best way to deal with meta-Trello issues?

(I can always just email everyone but I would like to keep it in Trello if possible.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been implemented sometime since this question was asked.

Notify all members of the board:

> @board

Notify all members of the card:

> @card

Answer (score 1):

That's something we've talked about but have never decided to actually add. You can certainly have everyone on the board subscribe to one of the cards on the board (called 'Announcements' or something like that, and then they'll get notifications for any comments you make on that card.